# How is this Javascript counting loop working? - Creating output of a Quiz

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to build a javascript quiz that isn't "right" or "wrong," but gives an output on a scale. These quizzes are for personal taste, personality, etc. So, "What superhero are you?"

I've been trying to use this JSON/Javascrpt here: https://github.com/jbierfeldt/bf-quiz/blob/master/bf-quiz.js

I'm really hung up on the calcResult. I've been trying to debug it, and I can't figure out what its doing. Is it keeping track of a highest number of an individual group `highest` and then only modifying `highest_score` when something larger comes up? **I can't figure out how the output of this aligns with a defined number result answer.**

```
calcResult = function calcResult() {
    var highest = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        results[i].countof = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < userAnswers.length; j++) {
            if (userAnswers[j] == results[i].result.id) {
                results[i].countof++;
            }
        }
        if (results[i].countof > highest) {
            highest = results[i].countof;
            highest_score = results[i];
        }
    }
    //disable the inputs after the quiz is finished
    writeResult();
    disableAnswers();
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. I added (slightly generic) comments to the code for you.

What it does is find the result that most users have picked as an answer (whatever a result is in your use case).

```
calcResult = function calcResult() {
    // used to keep track of the maximum userAnswers for one result
    var highest = 0;

    // iterate through all results...
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

        // used to count how many userAnswers exist for this result
        results[i].countof = 0;
        // iterate through userAnswers and...
        for (var j = 0; j < userAnswers.length; j++) {
            // find userAnswers that are for current result
            if (userAnswers[j] == results[i].result.id) {
                // if we are here, we found a userAnswer for the
                // current result. Therefore, we increment the
                // number of userAnswers for the result.
                results[i].countof++;
            }
        }

        // check if the current result has the highest number of    
        // userAnswers so far
        if (results[i].countof > highest) {
            // if so, set the new maximum number of userAnswers per
            // result to the number of userAnswers of the current
            // result
            highest = results[i].countof;

            // store this result as the one with the most userAnswers
            highest_score = results[i];
        }
    }
    //disable the inputs after the quiz is finished
    writeResult();
    disableAnswers();
},
```

Comment: Okay, so one thing that really confused me was the fact that the last question on the default JSON had only two options, a -1 and a 5. Does that mean the -1 answer literally does nothing?  I was also doing a document.print of "highest" (or something like that, I don't really know js) and lots of times I was getting numbers like 25, and 10 when all answers selected had values of 0

Comment: If I understand the quiz use case correctly, highest just references the type of result that most users got. For example here https://github.com/jbierfeldt/bf-quiz/blob/master/bf-json/quiz_image.json, `highest_score=1` would mean that most users are 'Max Palevsky' and `highest=25` would mean that 25 users are 'Max Palevsky'.

Comment: so, to be clear, the computation of answers is counting which "id" was answered the most, and then display the answer under Quiz Results of the most used id? That is what I thought it would do, but when I'm testing it, it doesn't seem to be accomplishing it.

Comment: Yes, `writeResult` takes `highest_score` and renders its content as the quiz result.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I don't know why it was giving me weird stuff earlier. It seems to be working fine now. Mostly a user error with JSON I beleive.

Answer (score 0):

`highest` is the numerical value of the score. `highest_score` is the referenced object that has the highest score. It's really redundant code in some respects. The last `if` statement could be refined as this:

```
    if (!highest_score || results[i].countof > highest_score.countof) {
        highest_score = results[i];
    }
```

And then you could just remove the `highest` variable altogether, and reference `highest_score` and `highest_score.countof` instead. Such as this:

```
calcResult = function calcResult() {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        results[i].countof = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < userAnswers.length; j++) {
            if (userAnswers[j] == results[i].result.id) {
                results[i].countof++;
            }
        }
        if (!highest_score || results[i].countof > highest_score.countof) {
            highest_score = results[i];
        }
    }
    //disable the inputs after the quiz is finished
    writeResult();
    disableAnswers();
},
```

But I wouldn't recomnmend doing that. The library probably references `highest` elsewhere in the code.

Comment: One thing that really confused me was the fact that the last question on the default JSON (here https://github.com/jbierfeldt/bf-quiz/blob/master/bf-json/BuildingsQuiz2.json ) had only two options, a -1 and a 5. Does that mean the -1 answer literally does nothing (throwaway answer)? I was also doing a document.print of "highest" (or something like that, I don't really know js) and lots of times I was getting numbers like 25, and 10 when all answers selected had values of 0